# 'DisplaySessionContainer1' files inside ProgramData directory of C drive

Tags: windows, logging

There are about 100+ files named 'DisplaySessionContainer1' and 'DisplaySessionContainer1.log_backup1' in my 'C:\ProgramData' path. I cannnot find the reason where they are coming from. Please help me solve this.

[The lines look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhuqb.png)

Answer (score 0):

These files are Nvidia Telemetry.
My personal advice is to leave them alone, and contact NVIDIA Support if they become
too numerous.

Blocking these jobs is getting and harder to block and may impact on the correct
functioning of the software. But the following methods may help:

- Disable in Task Scheduler, Task Scheduler Library, all tasks whose name
  start with `NvTm`
- Delete `DisplayDriverRAS` under folders
  `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Display.NvContainer\plugins\LocalSystem`
  and
  `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\`
- Delete or rename `nvtelemetry.dll` by searching for it on the disk
- Try the program
  [Disable-Nvidia-Telemetry](https://github.com/Sleepydragn1/Disable-Nvidia-Telemetry)
  (last updated in 2018).

Whatever method works for you may need to be redone when a new NVIDIA driver
version is installed.